# In-route encryption of sensitive files from WinSCP to S3 (AWS)

Tags: ssh, encryption, routing, sftp

Let me preface this question by saying I am new to Native AWS and know the basics but am curious if there is a solution to this niche problem I am facing.

I have a need to encrypt files in route that are uploaded in WinSCP and sent to an S3. I am currently using AWS Transfer Family to establish an SSH key pair that is used to authenticate the WinSCP client with the Transfer Family protocol that eventually sends the file to my target S3 bucket. I have encryption setup on my S3 bucket and the SSH ensures that only someone with access to the private key can drop to my bucket but as the files are in transit from WinSCP to S3 is there a way to encrypt the files themselves as they are moved.

I am essentially trying to replicate a process similar to PGP encryption but within the WinSCP -> Transfer Family -> S3 work flow I have built.

Hopefully this rewording helps establish what I am trying to ask.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by *"files dropped in WinSCP"*.

Comment: You are using SFTP to upload the files with WinSCP to the S3. The SFTP itself is encrypted.  What do you need the additional encryption for?